# Is there anyway to request a specific value in Facebook's Graph API not using FQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

e.g.

```
FB.api('/me/permissions="user_photos"', function (response) { });
```

instead of

```
FB.api({ method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT user_photos FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()' }, function(resp) {
    for(var key in resp[0]) {
        if(resp[0][key] === "1")
            console.log(key+' is granted')
        else
            console.log(key+' is not granted')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Theres a way called selection in graph api or more advance [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/):

You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the "fields" query parameter, Example:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions?fields=user_photos', function (response) { });
```

Graph API Explorer [Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/permissions?fields=user_photos)

**EDIT:**
Quoted directly from graph api doc:

> **Selection**
>
> By default, most object properties are returned when you make a query.
>   You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the
>   "fields" query parameter. For example, this URL will only return the
>   id, name, and picture of Ben:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=id,name,picture
>
> You can also request multiple objects in a single query using the
>   "ids" query parameter. For example, the URL
>   https://graph.facebook.com?ids=arjun,vernal returns both profiles in
>   the same response.
>
> The "ids" query parameter also accepts URLs. This is useful for
>   finding IDs of URLs in the Open Graph. For example:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
>
> Additionally, there is a special identifier me which refers to the
>   current user. So the URL https://graph.facebook.com/me returns the
>   active user's profile.
>
> When retrieving Posts via the /home, /feed, or /posts connection, you
>   can restrict the results to only those with a location attached by
>   adding with=location to the URL parameters:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?with=location

Source: [Graph API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)